# How do I load text from a file into a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a support site for my business. The way that I decided to do this was to create an accordion menu and allow the user to select from a list of FAQs. When the user clicks the FAQ, I want the page to pull the answer from another text file in the directory that contains the answer, then display it in a div.

Is there a way to do this without Ajax, PHP, or JQuery? Javascript is okay, as that's the only one I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

> When the user clicks the FAQ, I want the page to pull the answer from another text file in the directory that contains the answer

Where is the text file and directory stored? Presumably, somewhere on your server.

And the process of pulling a file from the server from a HTML page is commonly called AJAX.

So, to directly answer your question: no, not possible. You need AJAX to do what you described.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted an honest question but I appreciate the honest answer. I'll look more into AJAX and see if I can get it working. Also, I'd upvote you but I don't have 15 reputation yet. Sorry

Comment: No problem. Do read up more, and if you run into issues, post a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution to this is to put all of the answers in the page and have them hidden by default. Then show the answer for the FAQ that is clicked upon. This assumes the answers are not overly lengthy (at that point, maybe they should be on a separate page or you could introduce AJAX and load them dynamically).